# Testing observable from angular service, angular4

Tags: angular

I want to test Observable return data, in angular component.

I have created a slackblitz `https://stackblitz.com/edit/observable-testing-101`.

Here you can see the logic for component + service.

My testing code is also included in slack.

On my local m/c I am getting erro : `Expected undefined to be 1.`

Please help, I am new to testing angular.

Comment: When u get this exception?

Comment: on ng test, I am getting this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: to do testing in stackblitz requires a different setup than what you have above.  I have copied your data over into an Angular Stackblitz testing environment here: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53039354?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts

Since you are using Angular 4 I had to install rxjs.compat in order to run your code in the stackblitz because I am using Angular 7 there.

Once I had it set up, the first thing I ran into was this:

```
Failed: <spyOn> : getPostObservable() method does not exist 
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
```

Sure enough, `getPostObservable()` does not exist in the data.service.ts file you put up in stackblitz.  However, `getTodoObservable()` does exist, so I changed the test to point to that function.

Then I got the message you refer to above:

```
Expected undefined to be 1
```

I noticed you have TWO instances of fixture.detectChanges(), one in a `beforeEach()` before the specs and another in the spec for 'Should get todo from observable'.  The first time you call fixture.detectChanges it will call the lifecyclehook for initialization and ngOnInit() will get executed, so you want to be careful you have set up any spies you need to use within ngOnInit() BEFORE calling this.  I commented out the first call, and the test now works.

I also commented out the 'whenStable' since that is also not needed here - you are returning an observable with 'of' that immediately resolves, so no need for this.  I also commented out your call to console.log(this.response) since you don't have a response object defined and it was giving 'undefined' in the console output.  I also added console.log(component) since I find this useful to output when trying to figure out why the component doesn't look the way I expect it to.  (In case you didn't know, click the word 'Console' in the bottom of the dev server testing window to open up the console log.)

One final observation: I really don't like seeting the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA being used for testing.  I never use it myself since it tends to cover over real issues by not reporting them, and I would like to see them and fix them.  :)

Comment: Excellent, sir. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate the hard work you put, to get things working and explaining. Thanks Again. Just one more question, how can I use providers: [{provide: DataService, useClass: MockDataService}], in this.

Comment: After all the other users on StackOverflow have given to me, I'm happy to give something back - pay it forward and all that.  :)  

I updated the stackblitz with how I would do this.  Note: I used `{provide: DataService: useValue: mockDataService}`, using useValue instead of useClass.  I also created the mock (really a spy) above with `const mockDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj({ getTodoObservable: of(responseObservable) });` Now there is no need to SpyOn the service, you've injected the spy already.  I like to keep things simple.

Comment: Thanks, I got this, but just asking, is it possible to use useClass, with all methods, rather than useValue. if yes than how. Please make new spec.ts file, if possible.

Comment: Ok, I renamed the old .spec file, (it is called "old-my-component-spec.ts").  I added a mock Class and injected that.  Is that what you were looking for?  Note that the spyOn inside the spec now does .and.callThrough() instead of returning a different value.  How much of the actual class you want to implement depends on what you want to test.  Note - this is the spec for the component, not the service.  I'm sure you will unit test the service by mocking Http, but you don't want to do that in the component test.

Comment: Excellent sir, I wish I could chat with you for some queries, but that will be too much for the asking. Thanks a lot again.